# Bash mysql array do not get empty value

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash, string

My Bash script makes an array from MySQL:

```
info_tmp=$(mysql --batch --silent -u root -ppassword database -e "SELECT id,info1,info2 FROM table WHERE id=1")
info=($(for i in $info_tmp;do echo $i;done))
info1=${info[1]}
```

My problem is, that, if info1 is an empty string in the database, then $info1 became info2.
How can I put an empty string into $info array?

```
Mysql Database: 
Id | info1 | info2 
 1 |       | data2 
 2 | data3 | data4 

$info_tmp 
1 data2 
2 data3 data4
```

Thank you for your answer

#### This is the final code that worked (@Barmar):

```
IFS="|"
info_tmp=$(mysql --batch --silent -u root -ppassword database -e "SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', id,info1,info2) FROM table WHERE id=1")
info=(${info_tmp// / })
info1=${info[1]}
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples of ``info_tmp`` variable?

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko The problem is that when one of the columns in the database is an empty string, bash just sees a pair of TAB characters, which is treated as one delimiter rather than two delimiters around an empty value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a character that shouldn't appear in any of the columns, use that as a delimiter.

```
IFS="|"
info_tmp=$(mysql --batch --silent -u root -ppassword database -e "SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', id,info1,info2) FROM table WHERE id=1")
```

This works because bash doesn't merge sequences of non-whitespace delimiters in IFS, only whitespace characters.

I'm not sure what the point of the `for` loop that copies `$info_tmp` to `$info` is, but you need to do the same thing there. If you use whitespace as your word delimiter, you'll never be able to get empty array values from command substitution.

Comment: Thank You @Barmar, it seems it works, I can loop through $info_tmp `for i in $info_tmp ; do echo $i ; done` but I can't access to the array elements like `echo ${info_tmp[1]}` How can I access the individual elements?

Comment: When I tested this, I didn't have any problem accessing `${info_tmp[1]}`.

Comment: This way works: After your code `info=(${info_tmp// / })` Then `${info[1]}` is info1

Answer (score 0):

What about temporarily adding a single character in your for-loop:

```
info_tmp=$(mysql --batch --silent -u root -ppassword database -e "SELECT id,info1,info2 FROM table WHERE id=1")
info=($(for i in $info_tmp;do echo " "$i;done))
info1=$(${info[1]} | cut -c 2-)
```

Comment: The problem is in the assignment to `info_tmp`, not `info`.